# Code ignores row count

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system where the user sends an invitation, and once the official accepts, it will be saved to the database and sync to the official's calendar.

I'm trying to run a query where it checks if there are any events on that current time. Basically if it returns at least 1, it means the invitation wont send because there is a conflict but it just ignores the row count from MySQL database. Here is my code:

```
// variables
$id = $_GET['id'];
$dStart = $_POST['dStart'];
$dEnd = $_POST['dEnd'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$time_end = $_POST['time_end'];

// convert them into date formats
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dStart));
$date2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dEnd));
$time_f = date("H:i:s", strtotime($time));
$time_end_f = date("H:i:s", strtotime($time_end));

// set default timezone
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
// check if date is occupied
$query_check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM events WHERE (date_start = '$date') AND ((`time` BETWEEN '$time_f' AND '$time_end_f') OR (`time_end` BETWEEN '$time_f' AND '$time_end_f')) AND pastor_id = '$id' AND invite = 0 AND reschedule = 0") or die (mysqli_error($con));
$fetch_check = mysqli_fetch_array($query_check);
if ($fetch_check['total'] >= 1) {
    echo "<center><p>Sorry, this time is occupied. Please select another schedule</p><p>If you haven't, please refer to this pastor's calendar which can be found by <a href='profile.php?id=$id&grid=true'>clicking here.</a></p></center>";
} else {
    // generate random reference code
    $ref_code = rand(1000000, 9999999);
    $_SESSION['reference_code'] = $ref_code;
    $ref_code_final = $_SESSION['reference_code'];
    // insert to events table
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `events` (`id`, `reference_code`, `name`, `description`, `date_start`, `date_end`, `time`, `time_end`, `pastor_id`, `pastor`, `category`, `venue`, `invite`, `sender_name`, `sender_address`, `sender_phone`) VALUES (NULL, '$ref_code_final', '$name', '$description', '$date', '$date2', '$time', '$time_end', '$id', '$pastor', '$category', '$venue', '1', '$sender', '$address', '$phone')");

    header("Location: send.php?sendid=$id&success");
}
```

I checked so many times on PHPMyAdmin, the query returns at least 1 from my database. I made another .php file and ran the query there, echoed the result and it still outputs 1. But for some reason, when I use the query here it **COMPLETELY** ignores the `if statement` and goes directly to `else`

Comment: I'd just `select top 1 1` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)` then convert that to boolean for your check. Though not sure on executing scalar queries in php mysql. This would return `1` if there is an overlap and `null` if there is no overlap.

Comment: Where is `$id` in your SQL statement being set?

Comment: @NigelRen may have it, if it works on PHPMyAdmin because you're setting the pastor ID properly, but in your PHP you're forgetting to, so it's looking for a null pastor.

Comment: @NigelRen I edited the post. I forgot to include it, but it basically looks like that. I have a URL that says `send.php?sendid=18` and it basically gets the ID from that